# Best way to store a "Last execution date" in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Every day I run a pipeline that runs a Copy Data activity (DB2 => Parquet file).

How can I store the "Last execution date" of this activity?

Is there a best practice solution?

Because it would be unfortunate if we must do this in the old school way (store the date in a text file, or SQL Table, ...)

Thanks.

Comment: where you want to store that last execution date of pipeline?

Comment: I don't have a specific place. Is there a best way to do it ? Without writing it to a file (text file, parquet, ...) and reading it later. May be the best practice it's to store it in a SQL Serverless ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Best way to store a "Last execution date" in Azure Data Factory

The SQL table Is the best way to store the `Last Execution Date` of activity or pipeline because **In SQL table you can update the value as well as append the value**.  But **in csv file, text file you cannot append the value in it. It will just overwrite that value**.

To store the value in SQL Table you can follow below procedure:
Simply you can use `script activity` after that `copy activity` with **Insert query** and `@utcnow()` function.

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know as to when a ADF was triggered by a scheduled  trigger . You can use this API .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/trigger-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "triggerName": "exampleTrigger",
      "triggerRunId": "08586724970898148904457116912CU27",
      "triggerType": "ScheduleTrigger",
      "triggerRunTimestamp": "2018-06-16T00:43:15.660141Z",
      "status": "Succeeded",
      "message": "",
      "properties": {
        "TriggerTime": "6/16/2018 12:43:15 AM",
        "ScheduleTime": "6/16/2018 12:43:14 AM"
      },
      "triggeredPipelines": {
        "examplePipeline": "9f3ce8b3-37d7-43eb-96ac-a656c0476283"
      }
    }
  ]
```

}

and for Pipelines runs you can use the API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "runId": "2f7fdb90-5df1-4b8e-ac2f-064cfa58202b",
      "pipelineName": "examplePipeline",
      "parameters": {
        "OutputBlobNameList": "[\"exampleoutput.csv\"]"
      },
      "invokedBy": {
        "id": "80a01654a9d34ad18b3fcac5d5d76b67",
        "name": "Manual"
      },
      "runStart": "2018-06-16T00:37:44.6257014Z",
      "runEnd": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
      "durationInMs": 28105,
      "status": "Succeeded",
      "message": "",
      "lastUpdated": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
      "annotations": [],
      "runDimension": {
        "JobId": "79c1cc52-265f-41a5-9553-be65e736fbd3"
      }
    },
    {
      "runId": "16ac5348-ff82-4f95-a80d-638c1d47b721",
      "pipelineName": "examplePipeline",
      "parameters": {
        "OutputBlobNameList": "[\"exampleoutput.csv\"]"
      },
      "invokedBy": {
        "id": "7c5fd7ef7e8a464b98b931cf15fcac66",
        "name": "Manual"
      },
      "runStart": "2018-06-16T00:39:49.2745128Z",
      "runEnd": null,
      "durationInMs": null,
      "status": "Cancelled",
      "message": "",
      "lastUpdated": "2018-06-16T00:39:51.216097Z",
      "annotations": [],
      "runDimension": {
        "JobId": "84a3c493-0628-4b44-852f-ef5b3a11bdab"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```